# Trouble with ec2_vpc_subnet module

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to run the following play

```
- name: Create subnet for database servers
  ec2_vpc_subnet:
    state: present
    region: "us-east-1"
    vpc_id: "vpc-abcd1234"
    cidr: "10.10.10.0/28"
    resource_tags:
      Name: "Subnet"
  register: subnet
```

Every time I run the playbook the subnet recreates

Here is my -vvvv output

```
changed: [localhost] => {
  "changed": true,
  "invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "aws_access_key": null,
        "aws_secret_key": null,
        "az": "us-east-1b",
        "cidr": "10.0.10.0/28",
        "ec2_url": null,
        "profile": null,
        "region": "us-east-1",
        "resource_tags": {
            "Name": "subnet"
        },
        "security_token": null,
        "state": "present",
        "tags": {
            "Name": "subnet"
        },
        "validate_certs": true,
        "vpc_id": "vpc-abcd1234"
    },
    "module_name": "ec2_vpc_subnet"
  },
  "subnet": {
    "availability_zone": "us-east-1b",
    "available_ip_address_count": 11,
    "cidr_block": "10.0.10.0/28",
    "default_for_az": "false",
    "id": "subnet-cc399de1",
    "map_public_ip_on_launch": "false",
    "state": "available",
    "tags": {
        "Name": "subnet"
    },
    "vpc_id": "vpc-abcd1234"
  }
}
```

Is anyone else having this issue?  It would be great to build subnets outside of ec2_vpc module and have them be stable.

Thanks

Comment: What makes you to think it is recreating the subnet?

Comment: If you modify subnet tags somewhere later, this task may delete tags, but not recreate the subnet.

Comment: @helloV - Well, the TASK changes and the subnet id changes in AWS.  The old subnet id is no longer instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue myself.  I had been using ec2_vpc module higher up the playbook to deploy AWS VPC, IGW, & subnets.  I moved my Task to ec2_vpc and adjusted the downstream keys.

My ec2_vpc_subnet tasks no longer change after runs

Thanks